# (Pandas) drop duplicated groups created by GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, data-manipulation

I'd like to create groups by a custom ID, and then eliminate groups that are duplicates in some columns.

For example

```
| id | A   | B  |
|----|-----|----|
| 1  | foo | 40 |
| 1  | bar | 50 |
| 2  | foo | 40 |
| 2  | bar | 50 |
| 2  | cod | 0  |
| 3  | foo | 40 |
| 3  | bar | 50 |
```

to

```
| id | A   | B  |
|----|-----|----|
| 1  | foo | 40 |
| 1  | bar | 50 |
| 2  | foo | 40 |
| 2  | bar | 50 |
| 2  | cod | 0  |
```

Here I grouped by id and then i removed 3 because, if we only consider columns A and B, they are identical, while group 2 has some duplicated rows but its not an exact copy.

I've tried looping over groups but its very slow even tho there is only around 12.000 groups. One possible complication is that groups have variable sizes.

Here is the solution ive been working on but its taking way to long with no aparent duplicated hits (which i know exists in this db)

```
grps = datafinal.groupby('Form_id') 
unique_grps={}

first=True
for lab1, grp1 in grps:
    if first:
        unique_grps[lab1] = grp1
        first=False
        continue
    for lab2, grp2 in unique_grps.copy().items():
        if grp2[['A','B']].equals(grp1[['A','B']]):
            print("hit")
            continue
        unique_grps[lab1] = grp1
```

Comment: Can't you just drop duplicates w.r.t. columns A and B first?

Comment: @timgeb I don't think that will work. Imagine group 2 had 1 of the rows of group 3 and group 1 had the other. `drop_duplicates` would remove group 3 even though it's not fully duplicated by one group.

Comment: @timgeb that would remove group 2 first two rows, which i need to keep.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Can you use the built-in [drop duplicates](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with the subset as `'A', 'B'` on your result DF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `agg` `tuple` and `duplicated`

```
s=df.groupby('id').agg(tuple).sum(1).duplicated()
df.loc[df.id.isin(s[~s].index)]
Out[779]: 
   id    A   B
0   1  foo  40
1   1  bar  50
2   2  foo  40
3   2  bar  50
4   2  cod   0
```

More info : Right now , everything within the group is in one `tuple`

```
df.groupby('id').agg(tuple).sum(1)
Out[780]: 
id
1            (foo, bar, 40, 50)
2    (foo, bar, cod, 40, 50, 0)
3            (foo, bar, 40, 50)
dtype: object
```

---

Update

```
from natsort import natsorted
s=df.groupby('id').agg(tuple).sum(1).map(natsorted).map(tuple).duplicated()
```

Comment: Nice, this gets me 90% there, however I need to specify a subset of the columns i want to check for duplicates, (for simplicity I didn't add more columns in my example but say there are 5 columns and the other 3 I don't care about)

Comment: Oh but i can just subset the dataframe on the first step can't I? This would work then.

Comment: I think perhaps `.sort_values` first incase the order of rows isn't consistent within groups?

Comment: @user3207377 you can just filter at the first step , then you can achieve what you need

Comment: @ALollz indeed i'm now looking at sorting the values. I'm unsure at which point though.

Comment: @W-B I used this but it give a typerror since there are some NoneTypes being compared to Int :/.

Comment: @user3207377 maybe fill the np.nan with `NaN` ?

Comment: `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 3), indices imply (3, 2)`   for `df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2,3,3],
          'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'cod','foo','bar'],
          'B': [40, 50, 40, 50, 0,40,50]})`

Comment: @astro123 `s=df.groupby('id').agg(tuple).sum(1).map(natsorted).map(tuple).duplicated()
`

Comment: @W-B sorry, still get the same error. `df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 2,3,3],
          'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'cod','foo','bar'],
          'B': [40, 50, 40, 50, 0,40,50]})

s=df.groupby('id').agg(tuple).sum(1).map(natsorted).map(tuple).duplicated()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`unique_everseen` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) from the `itertools` docs (also found in the [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.unique_everseen) library), together with `pd.concat` and `groupby`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from more_itertools import unique_everseen

def unique_key(x):
    return tuple(map(tuple, x[['A', 'B']].values.tolist()))

def jpp(df):
    groups = map(itemgetter(1), df.groupby('id'))
    return pd.concat(unique_everseen(groups, key=unique_key))

print(jpp(df))

   id    A   B
0   1  foo  40
1   1  bar  50
2   2  foo  40
3   2  bar  50
4   2  cod   0
```

Comment: this is awesome! if the order in two groups are different but the values the same, would that count as a duplicate or a unique group?